# How do "Tag synonyms" get accepted?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

I have added a number of "Tag Synonyms" and there is another that to me make a lot of sense to either be merged with another tag, or at least redirected.  They have been marked as "pending" for 3 months.

How do these get reveiwed by other users or the moderators in order to get accepted or dropped (if they don't make sense)?

Comment: I am unaware of any synonyms waiting for moderator approval.  Could you indicate how you find out which ones are "pending"?

Comment: @whuber, take a look at [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all).  Arcobjects.net, large-datasets, datasets, dataset, shp, script.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan.  It looks like mods are not automatically notified of synonym requests.  I'll make an effort to review these periodically.  In the meantime, I approved all but one of the pending synonyms.  (I feel that people using the "large-datasets" tag may be indicating something in addition to "datasets," so I'm reluctant to lose that information by making them synonyms.)

Comment: Thanks for checking and approving.  I'm fine with whatever decisions are made in the best interest of the community.

Comment: Hey, we're not perfect, so discussion is always welcome.  The interface provided for making and approving synonyms (and other tag-related things) is limited and impersonal, so it's usually difficult to communicate one's reasoning.  If you see anything that could be improved, please flag it and a moderator will look into it; if you're not satisfied with the result, we always have these meta pages!

Comment: It is really hard to find these suggestions. Currently there is a suggestion in there for almost 1 1/2 years having only one review. Maybe SE should place them somewhere else, maybe just include them in the same menu as all the other reviews.

Answer (score 3):

To see all the tags then synonyms go to:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=renames&filter=all

*"Every question on Stack Overflow, or any other Stack Exchange site, must be tagged with at least one tag. Tags are simple keywords or labels that help categorize your question with other, similar questions"*

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

*"We added tag merging about a year ago, but it was purely a moderator function. We’ve also slowly but surely been increasing the reputation required to create a new tag from 250 reputation, to 500 reputation, all the way to the current setting of 1500 reputation. **We’ve also started automatically culling single-use tags that are more than 6 months old**."*

Moderators do have the option to accept or decline the changes or merge tags but there is some clean-up from the Stack Exchange employees.